# JS - Can't find user location

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbconnect

Using the facebook js api i can get the user current location but the values are city id + city name in English. 
I need the **city name in Hebrew**. I know facebook keeps the Hebrew name because when you update your profile with location in  Hebrew Facebook finds the city and display the name in English.
I'm using this code to get the user details.

```
FB.api('/me', { fields: ...
```

thanks

Comment: You need to actually put a question in here to get any kind of constructive response. Tell us exactly what programatic task you're stuck with. Give code samples of what you have so far and write what bits you are missing. Simply saying "I want to do X, write it for me" wont get you any answers.

Answer (score 1):

The result that you are getting is not `city id + city name`, its a JSON. [Read more about JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Suppose your result is:

```
var result = FB.api('/me?fields=location');
```

then you can acces the city name with -

```
var city_name = result.location.name;
```

Comment: Any Ideas ? is there any way to ask the facebook developers directly ?